# How to force Matlab/Octave cov function to use optional parameter

Tags: matlab, octave, covariance

I'm using the **cov** (covariance) function of Matlab and Octave. Actually I'm using **Octave**, but in the end it has to work for both. This function has an optional second or third parameters to indicate whether **normalization** should be done with **N** or N-1.

If I do this: `cov(points,1)` (where points is 4x2 matrix) I get following error:

```
error: cov: x and y must have the same number of observations
```

On a general note I would like to know how is Matlab/Octave able to distinguish if the second parameter is another matrix or an optional parameter (because it can have 2 or 3 parameters).

More specifically I would like to know **how can I solve my problem?**

Matlab cov() documentation: http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/cov.html
Octave cov() documentation: http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Correlation-and-Regression-Analysis.html

EDIT: I'm using Octave 3.2.4 on Ubuntu 12.04 
EDIT2: The solution is to install a newer version of Octave. This features was implemented after 3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type `help cov`, and note that `opt` <strike>has been removed</strike> doesn't exist.

better yet, do

```
gedit /usr/share/octave/3.2.4/m/statistics/base/cov.m
```

and compare it to the <strike>old</strike> new [code](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/05635e4c605a/scripts/statistics/base/cov.m#l60)

Opt is <strike>gone</strike> recent. Use Oli's trick in the meantime

**Edit**: I take that back, this is a new feature. Not sure which version of Octave is using it, but you need an upgrade. Either, you do an unstable synaptic upgrade if you can find a repository, or you build it from source.

**Edit 2**: feature added Jan 2011 (3.4.1). 3.2.4 released Jan 2010. current version is 3.6.1

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an Octave bug (at least with version 3.0.5); it works fine in Matlab (at least with version 7.10).

Of course, to work around, you could just compute:

```
cov(a) * (N-1) / N
```

Comment: Maybe someone could confirm this... I can't try it out in Matlab because I have no license at home...

Comment: I mean confirm that it doesn't work in Octave. I trust you when you say it does in Matlab ;-)

Comment: @OmarKohl: I tried it in Octave too, but the version I have is quite out of date...